# PHP Skip foreach loop on same value

Tags: php

i work on a simple price compare and i want the output clean as possible. The basic array of my data looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 84 [system_id] => 174 [url] => https://firstshop-pricecheck.com/url-1 [shopid] => First Shop [price] => {"price": "32 00", "amount": "10", "variation": "standard"} [currency] => EUR ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 85 [system_id] => 174 [url] => https://firstshop-pricecheck.com/url-2 [shopid] => First Shop [price] => {"price": "18 00", "amount": "3", "variation": "other"}, {"price": "28 01", "amount": "5", "variation": "standard"}, {"price": "49 00", "amount": "10", "variation": "other"}, {"price": "108 00", "amount": "25", "variation": "standard"} [currency] => EUR ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 106 [system_id] => 174 [url] => https://secondshop-pricecheck.com/url-1 [shopid] => Second Shop [price] => {"price": "3 25", "amount": "1", "variation": "standard"}, {"price": "4 50", "amount": "1", "variation": "other"}, {"price": "32 50", "amount": "10", "variation": "standard"}, {"price": "45 00", "amount": "10", "variation": "other"} [currency] => GBP ) )
```

At first, we have a table header:

```
<table id="pricecheck" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Shop</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th>Payment</th>
                        <th>Amount / Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
```

At the moment, there is a new row for every shop (shopid), in the column "Amount / Price" i have another foreach to put the data in a simple select field.

```
<?php foreach ($array as $key => $value) { ?>
                        <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $value->shopid; ?></td>
                        <td>#Country</td>
                        <td>#Payment</td>
                        <td>
                        <?php 
                        # decode data to json:
                        $xmyson = $value->price . ', ';
                        $ymyson = rtrim($xmyson, ', ');
                        $zmyson = '{ "prices": [' . $ymyson . ']}';

                        $decode = json_decode($zmyson);
                        ?>
                        <select id="price_check_ordering" name="price_check_ordering" class="inputbox">
                            <?php
                            foreach ($decode->prices as $xvalue) { ?>
                            <option>
                             <?php 
                             $fprice = str_replace(" ", ",", $xvalue->price);
                             echo $fprice . ' €';
                            ?>
                            </option>
                            <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                           ?>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                                  <?php } ?>
```

Now, for the first loop: if it's the same shop (shopid), dont create another row - BUT create another select in that row with the data. So there is not a new row for the same shop, but another simple select field under "Amount / Price" with the relative data. I try to figure out a good logic to solve this.

Comment: Is the array ordered by shopid?

Comment: Please reformat your code so we can read it without our heads tilted...

Comment: A bit off-topic, but you have no opening `<option>` tag in your loop that builds the select list

Comment: why are you building json manually, only to decode it back to an array/object? You're writing php - why not build the object directly?

Comment: @Andrew I think it would make more sense to just order by the id.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Yeah, thanks - i tweaked a little bit to post it here, missed this bracket. Fixed.

Comment: @MarcB I'm not that coding-genius, so sorry if it doesn't make much sense ... but when there is more than one result, it breaks the json-logic and that's why i build the comma-stuff. That part is working fine so far.

Comment: I was just asking because there is a solution that could work if it was ordered by shop id. Do you have control over the order?

Comment: @Andrew Yes i do, would be no problem to order by shopid.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy solution:

```
<?php 

//order array by id
usort($your_data, function($a, $b) {
    return $a->id > $b->id;
});

$outputKeys = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) { ?>
    if(!in_array($key, $outputKeys)){
        $outputKeys[] = $key;
        <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $value->shopid; ?></td>
                    <td>#Country</td>
                    <td>#Payment</td>
                    <td>
                    <?php 
                    # decode data to json:
                    $xmyson = $value->price . ', ';
                    $ymyson = rtrim($xmyson, ', ');
                    $zmyson = '{ "prices": [' . $ymyson . ']}';

                    $decode = json_decode($zmyson);
                    ?>
                    <select id="price_check_ordering" name="price_check_ordering" class="inputbox">
                        <?php
                 } //endif output your select
                        foreach ($decode->prices as $xvalue) { ?>
                        <option>
                         <?php 
                         $fprice = str_replace(" ", ",", $xvalue->price);
                         echo $fprice . ' €';
                        ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                       ?>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                              <?php } ?>
```